# Modify variables inside a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'd like to know if it is posible, having one or more variables to pass them into a function and get those variables modified. I think it is posible with objects, as they behave as references, but I don't know.

With 1 var you could do:

```
var something = increase(something);
```

but what if you have, for example, 2 variables with recipies, and would like to exchange them?

```
exchange_recipies(book1, book2);
```

You could do this but the variables are parameters inside the function... So is there another way that I'm missing?

EDIT: I know it can be done in many ways but I'll state some here that I don't like due to obvious limitations:

-Use global variables.

-Use objects

-Return an array and reasign.

EDIT2: this [Is it possible to change the value of the function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292159/is-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-the-function-parameter) helped me, but I think that answer is uncomplet and there are ways of doing this.

Comment: you could use, inside you function, window.book1 and window.book2 but I would not recommend that. 
Instead you could return an Array with 2 indexes or an Object with the function and re-assign the variable.
http://jsbin.com/nayitimoso/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I knew that, but I'm asking for a better way. The window solution only works for global variables, and returning an array would make the code less elegant

Comment: You're asking for pass-by-reference -- you've shot down all the existing ways to achieve something like the desired behavior. No amount of shouting "useless!" and "obviously!" is going to change that, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the value of the function parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292159/is-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-the-function-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variables are declared globally then you wouldn't need to pass them into the function since they can be addressed inside the function.

```
var something = 1
function bar(){
    something = increase(something);
}
```

For example.

This means you avoid changing the variables into parameters and can then address them from any function (dependant on nesting, ergo, if the variable is declared inside a function it can't be addressed outside of that function but can from a function inside)

```
function foo(){
    var something = 1
    function bar(){
        //works because it exists in the parent function
        something = increase(something)
    }
}

function foobar()
    //Something doesn't exist here so would return something = undefined
    something = increase(something)
}
```

Comment: This is useless, because the functions you are creating aren't reusable

Comment: The OP didn't clarify how he wanted the functions to be used, just that he wanted to change variables inside of a function.

This has now been amended, in which case this isn't totally valid to the usecase.

Comment: @Vandervals also as an aside where did the OP state that the functions (any of them) should be reuseable? I was only making the point that functions can be nested inside of each other and variables declared inside a function can then be modified by nested functions once more.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is pass these two parameters as objects:

```
exchange_recipies({ obj: book1 }, { obj: book2 });
```

and then inside finction you can operate on `obj` properties

```
function exchange_recipies(book1, book2)
{
   book1.obj = book2.obj;
   ...
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNRZZb

Comment: Well its not the -only- way, could also be done with the array if its just a simple list of variables but its certainly the best way for anything more complicated than that.

Comment: Well obviously! But I already said it could be done that way in my question from the begining!